# Trying to uniquely identify an amazon echo

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an echo setup and I need to store a value that is unique to each user, and this value must be accessible from the main echo application so that it may be POSTed to a different service.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.